# Entity Framework Disconnected POCO, relationships with huge record count

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-relationship

I use Entity Framework POCO in a layered architecture. We should work disconnected after getting entit(y/ies).
Assume that we have two entities:

```
public class Customer
{  
  public int Id;  
  public string Name;
  public virtual IList<Order> Orders;
}  

public class Order
{
  public int Id;
  ....
}
```

And assume that, there's one customer that has orders count of 1000.
In this case, we want to get orders of this customer which only done in current week in a service method.
How a Repository method and Service method should we have?

**EDIT**

I think I should extend my question.
First of all, I meant with "customer with 1000 orders", I don't want to get that customer. I want to get "Orders of a customer (with a known Id, assume, Customer.Id=5) which Order.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)".
It's easy with representing IQueryable objects.

```
public List<Order> GetOrdersInLastWeek(int CustomerId)  
{  
  Customer customer = (from c in ctx.Customers where c.Id == CustomerId).SingleOrDefault();  
  List<Order> ordersThatIWant = customer.Orders.Where(o => o.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).ToList();
  return ordersThatIWant;  
}
```

I'm curious about these: The code above runs well.
 - But, is it correct for ORM/N-Layer best practices? Because Order is not an "aggregate root", Customer is an "aggregate root".
 - Should I have to have this GetOrdersInLastWeek in CustomerService class, or OrderService class?
 - And the last and important one for me; If I have methods like GetOrdersInLastWeek, and other methods like this, what about "Customer.Orders" navigation property in other layers, (e.g. presentation layer) (assume we are working with POCO entities and disconnected)?
 - Another example; I want to do paging on Customer.Orders navigation property in the service method. How and where can I do this (I know how to do it, but I mean according to best practices)?

Comment: What do you mean with "*what about "Customer.Orders" navigation property in other layers*"?

Comment: I don't use extra DTO's to translate POCO's to UI layer. So, UI layer sees Orders navigation property of Customer class. But I will do every query on Orders, in OrderService class, so Customer.Orders is useless in UI layer in this case. Is this a correct way?

Comment: I can't say if it's correct or not. I don't understand though why you don't load a customer *including* the orders you need in UI layer (as in my example below)? For the other points I have edited my answer below (see "Edit" section).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a mix of eager and explicit loading for this purpose, for example with `DbContext` (EF => 4.1) something like:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomersWithOrders()
{
    using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var customers1 = ctx.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders)
            .Where(c => c.Orders.Count() < 1000)
            .AsEnumerable();

        var customers2 = ctx.Customers
            .Where(c => c.Orders.Count() >= 1000)
            .AsEnumerable();

        DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1*(today-DayOfWeek.Monday));
        DateTime sunday = monday.AddDays(6);
        foreach (var customer in customers2)
        {
            ctx.Entry(customer).Collection(c => c.Orders).Query()
                .Where(o => o.ShipDate >= monday && o.ShipDate <= sunday)
                .Load();
        }

        return customers1.Concat(customers2).ToList();
    }
}
```

The result will be composed by the results of `1 + 1 + customers2.Count` database queries. If the case that a customer has more than 1000 orders is rare I don't think that those multiple queries will be a big performance problem.

**Edit**

I would suggest to change your query. The problem is that you load a customer (query 1) and then trigger lazy loading of *all* orders (query 2). So, you potentially have already loaded much more than 1000 orders before you apply the filter in memory. You can avoid that by using:

```
public List<Order> GetOrdersInLastWeek(int CustomerId)  
{  
    var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
    var orders = ctx.Customers
        .Where(c => c.Id == CustomerId)
        .Select(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.Date > date))
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (orders == null)
        return null; // or create an empty list

    return orders.ToList();
}
```

About your questions:

> Should I have to have this GetOrdersInLastWeek in CustomerService
>   class, or OrderService class?

In `CustomerService`. Because your are loading data of a specific customer. But using the `OrderService` isn't that wrong either, in my opinion.

> I want to do paging on Customer.Orders navigation property in the
>   service method. How and where can I do this (I know how to do it, but
>   I mean according to best practices)?

With your current architecture you must do it in your service method (create queries with `Skip` and `Take`) because you are exposing in-memory collections, i.e. materialized results from the service methods. So, you shouldn't page outside of the service because it would force you to load *all* data before you can page. The only alternative in my opinion is to return `IQueryable<T>` from the service and then page in UI layer by adding `Skip` and `Take` to the queries. But that would mean that you can't be disconnected in UI layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my focus is on a different point, so I extended/edited my question